# Which TextBox and PasswordBox controls arre these?

Tags: windows-phone-8, textbox, passwordbox

I was looking at Uber app for windows phone. Their registration screen looks like this.

[image: img 1][image: IMG 2]

Which controls are these? Do anyone know.

Comment: Textbox could be toolkit's PhoneTextBox. Although doesn't look like one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what they're using but you can recreate it using the Windows Phone Tool kit and some simple XAML.

For Textboxes

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60" Background="White" Margin="10,0" >
    <TextBlock Text="your_text" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" />
    <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="your hint" ActionIcon="/Assets/your_image.png"
                          Background="#00000000" BorderThickness="0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

For the Password box

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="70" Background="White" Margin="10,0" >
    <TextBlock Text="your_text" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" />
   <PasswordBox Password="test_password"/>
    <Image Source="/Assets/your_image.png"></Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: But this doesn't add a hint in PasswordBox. Also that image looks like part of the password control like action icon for PhoneTextBox

Comment: If you also want a hint for the PasswordBox, I think the solution is to have a <toolkit:PhoneTextBox> overlay the PasswordBox.  I'm pretty sure there is a solution on stack overflow awhile back that did exactly that.  Most these custom controls just rely on clever positioning of your elements + style.

Comment: Yes I have seen those solutions with textbox overlays. Will try with then. Thanks.